# Transform a for iteration of a List<MutablePair> in a String with java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

How can I get the Left part of a MutablePair list with Java 8 - streams, forEach or something? The code I want to transform in Java 8 type is:

```
for (MutablePair<String, Long> id: list) {
   if (null == value) {
      value = id.getLeft();
   } else {
      value += ", " + id.getLeft();
   }
}
```

So, if I have the list as: `[(OA,3853), (EE,866), (UN,728), (PP,10)]`, I need the value as: `OA, EE, UN, PP` as simple as possible. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `map` intermediate operation to transform to a `Stream<String>` then the `joining` collector to accumulate the elements into a single string separated by a `", "` delimiter:

```
list.stream()
    .map(pair -> pair.getLeft()) // or MutablePair::getLeft
    .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```

Answer (score 2):

```java
list.stream()
    .map(MutablePair::getLeft)
    .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```

There are couple of other options for `Collectors.joining` Read more about it [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining--)

Comment: you need the `stream` to use the `map` and `collect` operation

Comment: Yup, you are right. I forgot it. Done the edit. Thanks.